# How to center a div in flexbox when width>100%?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to center a `<div>` on my site, but I defined the width as 130% and now it's not centered anymore.

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

This is what I wrote schematically:

```css
.out {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.big {
  width: 130%;
  height: 130%;
  /* Pete's suggestion */
  position:relative;           /* add this so the left: 50% works */
  left:50%;                    /* move to middle of div */
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* move back left by half of own width */
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
div {
  display: flex;
}
.center {
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="out">
    <div class="big">
      Something
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndecmxbq/)

Comment: if you define width as 130% then you do something wrong

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: u can use center tag or else u can use margin : 0 auto

Comment: How can something 130% the size of its container appear centered?

Comment: @AkhilaPrakash [center tag is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) and should not be used and [margin auto will not center](https://jsfiddle.net/LLafnt0p/) an element if it is wider than it's parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use relative positioning with transform.  Here is an example:

```css
.outer {
  /* just for demo */
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.inner {
  width: 130%;
  position:relative;           /* add this so the left: 50% works */
  left:50%;                    /* move to middle of div */
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* move back left by half of own width */
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">

  </div>
</div>
```

Update as you have added some code:

```css
.out {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 200px;
  border: 4px solid lime;
}

.big {
  width: 130%;
  height: 130%;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  
  /* horizontal and vertical center (see above snippet if you only want to horizontally center) */
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
  /* center the contents of this div */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="big">
    Sonething
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
margin: 0 auto
```

in css div to center

Comment: margin auto won't work if the element is wider than the parent - https://jsfiddle.net/LLafnt0p/